# Required on Input type date inside a form doenst work

Tags: javascript, forms, required

I have a form with few inputs and for each of these inputs I made sure it's marked as "required."
 My intention is that if someone forgets to insert data in these spots, a tooltip will pop up to remind them.

I also added a code in Javascript so that when user click the button inside the form it won't automatically try to submit it.
But there's a twist:
I only set it up this way if all the inputs in the form have been filled. That way, the tooltip will be shown, but the form won't be sent.

Now, here's where things got interesting.
If someone leaves any of the inputs empty, the form notify them, Except for one type of input:
 the one that's meant for dates. For some reason, even if it's left empty, the form doesn't seem to care and submit. But, and here's the kicker, if I move that date spot above a certain "tags" section in the form, suddenly it starts working as I intended.
 I'm not exactly sure why this happens, Could you help me please?

Code:

```js
const categoriesBtn = document.getElementById("categories-btn")
const allCategoriesEl = document.querySelector(".categories-options")
const plusBtn = document.getElementById("plus-btn")
const formEl = document.getElementById("task-form")
const taskBox = document.querySelector(".task-box")
const taskCancelBtn = document.querySelector(".cancel")
const taskAddBtn = document.getElementById("task-add-btn")
const taskTitle = document.getElementById("task-title")
const taskDate = document.getElementById("date-task")
const taskDescription = document.getElementById("task-description")
const taskId = document.getElementById("task-id")
const allTasksLocalStorage = bringTasksLocalStorage()
const tasksContainer = document.querySelector(".tasks-container")
const todayBtnEl = document.getElementById("today-tasks-btn")
const currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
const workBtnEl = document.getElementById("work-btn")
const entertainmentBtnEl = document.getElementById("entertainment-btn")
const familyBtnEl = document.getElementById("family-btn")
const studyBtnEl = document.getElementById("study-btn")
const doneBtnEl = document.getElementById("done-tasks-btn")
const dateBtnEl = document.getElementById("pick-date-btn")
const searchByDateBTn = document.getElementById("input-date")
let taskIdCounter = 1
// when upload site show all the tasks in the local storage
tasksDisplayer(currentTasks)

// show/hide the categories on the menu

categoriesBtn.addEventListener("click", () => allCategoriesEl.classList.toggle("categories-options-none"))

// tasks box functionality 

plusBtn.addEventListener("click", function showTaskBox() {
  taskBox.classList.add("task-box-active")
})

taskCancelBtn.addEventListener("click", () => taskBox.classList.remove("task-box-active"));

//main tasks box functionality:
taskAddBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  if (formEl.checkValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }

  const taskTags = document.querySelector('input[name="tags"]:checked')

  let oldTaskId = +taskId.value
  console.log(`The oldTaskId is: ${oldTaskId}`)

  //if the task has id, that mean its edit if it doesnt so its new task

  if (oldTaskId) {
    // find the task that you want to edit and fill it with the changes
    console.log("Entering the Edit Section!")
    const currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
    const indexOfTaskNeedToBeEdited = currentTasks.findIndex(task => task.id === oldTaskId)
    currentTasks[indexOfTaskNeedToBeEdited] =


      {
        id: oldTaskId,
        title: taskTitle.value,
        description: taskDescription.value,
        tag: taskTags.value,
        date: taskDate.value
      }

    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(currentTasks))

    tasksDisplayer(bringTasksLocalStorage())
    taskAddBtn.innerText = "Add"

    //clear the value of the task Id so it wont enter to the edit mode all the time,cause if task id will stay it would keep and going in to the edit mode
    taskId.value = ""



  } else {

    //generate new unique id for the new task
    const newTaskId = taskIdCounter
    console.log(`the newTaskId is: ${newTaskId}`)
    taskIdCounter++
    let newTask = {
      id: newTaskId,
      title: taskTitle.value,
      description: taskDescription.value,
      tag: taskTags.value,
      date: taskDate.value,
      status: false
    }



    updateLocalStorageArray(newTask)
  }


  formEl.reset()
  taskBox.classList.remove("task-box-active")

  if (oldTaskId) {

    alert("Task has been updated!")
  } else {

    alert("Task has been added!")
  }

  tasksDisplayer(bringTasksLocalStorage())


})



/*1. insert the added task to the locals storage without deleting the existed tasks
2. each time the screen is loaded bring all the data in the local storage and show them on the screen
*/

//bring all the tasks from the local storage
function bringTasksLocalStorage() {
  let currentLocalStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
  if (currentLocalStorageData == null) {
    currentLocalStorageData = []
  }
  return currentLocalStorageData
}

//add a task to the current tasks array
function updateTasksArray(object) {

  let oldTasksArray = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  oldTasksArray.push(object)
  const newTasksArray = oldTasksArray
  return newTasksArray

}

// update tasks in the local storage
function updateLocalStorageArray(object) {
  const newTasksArray = updateTasksArray(object)
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(newTasksArray))

}

function tasksDisplayer(tasks) {


  const mostUpdatedTasksForHtml = tasks.map((task, index) => {
    return `<div class="single-task ${task.status ? 'single-task-done-design' : ""}" >

                    <div class="middle-line ${task.status ? 'middle-line-active' : ""}" id="middle-line-${index}"></div>
                    <div class="task-wrapper">

                    
                    <h1 id="task-title">${task.title}</h1>
                    <div class="single-task-buttons" onclick="openMenu(${index}, event)">
                        <div class="task-dots-menu"></div>
                        <div class="task-dots-menu"></div>
                        <div class="task-dots-menu"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="task-options" id="${index}">

                        <button onclick="editTask(${task.id}, event)">Edit...</button>
                        <button onclick="deleteTask()">Delete</button>

                    </div>
                    <div>${task.description}</div>
                            <p>${task.date}</p>
                            <div class="tag" id="${task.tag}-color"></div>
                            <div class="checked-btn">
                            
                                <input type="checkbox" id="done-${index}" onclick="markAsDone(${index},event)" ${task.status ? 'checked' : ""}  />
                                <label for="done-${index}">Done</label> 
                            </div>
                        
                    </div>

                </div>`

  })

  tasksContainer.innerHTML = mostUpdatedTasksForHtml


}

function openMenu(index) {

  const allTaskOptionsBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".task-options")
  const arrayAllTaskOptionsBoxes = Array.from(allTaskOptionsBoxes)



  arrayAllTaskOptionsBoxes.forEach((box, boxIndex) => {
    // console.log(boxIndex)
    if (index === boxIndex && !box.classList.contains("task-options-active")) {
      box.classList.add("task-options-active")
    } else {
      box.classList.remove("task-options-active")
    }

  })

}


function deleteTask() {

  const indexToDelete = event.target.closest(".task-options").id
  // console.log(indexToDelete);
  const currentArray = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  // console.log(currentArray)
  currentArray.splice(indexToDelete, 1)
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(currentArray))
  tasksDisplayer(bringTasksLocalStorage())

}

function editTask(id) {

  //change button from add to update
  taskAddBtn.innerText = "Update"

  //open the task box 
  taskBox.classList.add("task-box-active")
  // console.log(`id: ${id}`);

  // close buttons task menu (edit and delete)
  event.target.closest(".task-options").classList.remove("task-options-active");

  // getting the data of the designated task
  const currentTasksArray = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  const taskToEdit = currentTasksArray[id - 1]

  //task description
  taskDescription.value = taskToEdit.description

  //task title
  taskTitle.value = taskToEdit.title

  //task tag
  const tagToBeMarked = document.getElementById(taskToEdit.tag)
  tagToBeMarked.checked = true

  //task date
  taskDate.value = taskToEdit.date

  //task input
  taskId.value = taskToEdit.id



  // this code works but I needed to go that way cause I gave the Id to this line: <div class="tag" id="${task.tag}-color"></div> and only after I change the id of this line to id + color I could shorten the code from what I have beneath to what written in row 177-178
  // const inputsArrayNode = document.getElementsByName("tags")
  // const inputArrayHtml = Array.from(inputsArrayNode)
  // console.log(inputArrayHtml);
  // inputArrayHtml.forEach(input => {
  //     console.log(input.id)
  //     console.log(taskToEdit.tag)
  //     if (input.id === taskToEdit.tag) {
  //         console.log("CHECKED!");
  //         input.checked = true
  //     }
  // })

}

function markAsDone(index, event) {

  const currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  console.log(`then event target is: ${event.target.checked}`)
  currentTasks[index].status = event.target.checked
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(currentTasks))
  event.target.closest(".single-task").classList.toggle("single-task-done-design")
  document.getElementById(`middle-line-${index}`).classList.toggle("middle-line-active")
  // document.getElementById(`middle-line-${index}`).closest(".single-task").classList.toggle("single-task-done-design")

}


workBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  const workTasks = currentTasks.filter(task => task.tag === "work")
  tasksDisplayer(workTasks)
})

entertainmentBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  const workTasks = currentTasks.filter(task => task.tag === "entertainment")
  tasksDisplayer(workTasks)
})


familyBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  const workTasks = currentTasks.filter(task => task.tag === "family")
  tasksDisplayer(workTasks)
})


studyBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  const workTasks = currentTasks.filter(task => task.tag === "study")
  tasksDisplayer(workTasks)
})

studyBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  const workTasks = currentTasks.filter(task => task.tag === "study")
  tasksDisplayer(workTasks)
})

doneBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  const workTasks = currentTasks.filter(task => task.status === true)
  tasksDisplayer(workTasks)
})


dateBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  searchByDateBTn.style.display = "block"
  // let currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  // console.log(currentTasks[0].date)
  // const workTasks = currentTasks.filter(task => task.date === true)
  // tasksDisplayer(workTasks)
})

searchByDateBTn.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const requestedTask = searchByDateBTn.value
  let currentTasks = bringTasksLocalStorage()
  const onlyTaskInThisDate = currentTasks.filter(task => task.date === requestedTask)
  tasksDisplayer(onlyTaskInThisDate)
})
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <nav>
      <h1 class="app-name">DoIt</h1>
      <button id="today-tasks-btn">Today</button>
      <button id="pick-date-btn">Pick a Date</button>
      <input type="date" id="input-date" />
      <div class="categories-container">
        <button id="categories-btn">Categories ⬇</button>
        <div class="categories-options">
          <button id="work-btn">work</button>
          <button id="study-btn">study</button>
          <button id="family-btn">family</button>
          <button id="entertainment-btn">entertainment</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="done-tasks-btn">Done</button>
      <div class="done-tasks-container"></div>

    </nav>
    <button id="plus-btn">➕</button>
    <div class="main">
      <h2 class="date-task">Today</h2>
      <div class="tasks-container">


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="task-box">
      <div class="wrapper">

        <form action="" id="task-form">

          <div class="buttons-container">
            <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
            <button class="add-btn-inside-box" id="task-add-btn">Add</button>
          </div>

          <div class="title-area">
            <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
            <input type="text" placeholder="add a title..." id="task-title" required>
          </div>

          <div class="description-area">
            <h2 class="description">Description</h2>
            <textarea placeholder="add a title..." id="task-description" required></textarea>
          </div>



          <div class="tags-area">

            <h2 class="tags">Tags</h2>

            <input type="radio" id="work" name="tags" value="work" required>
            <p class="work-tag" style="display: inline;">Work</p>

            <input type="radio" id="study" name="tags" value="study" required>
            <p class="study-tag" style="display: inline;">Study</p>

            <input type="radio" id="entertainment" name="tags" value="entertainment" required>
            <p class="entertaiment-tag" style="display: inline;">Entertainment</p>

            <input type="radio" id="family" name="tags" value="family" required>
            <p class="family-tag" style="display: inline;">Family</p>

          </div>

          <div class="deadline">
            <h2 for="date-task">Deadline</h2>
            <input type="date" id="date-task" required />
          </div>

          <input type="hidden" id="task-id">


        </form>

      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Make sure all inputs have a name attribute; they won't be included with the form without that.

Comment: @mykaf They're not submitting the form to a server, so I don't think that's relevant.